# Having trouble figuring out how to use argsort to create an index on one array and use it to sort another (without flattening)

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have an array called `ranks` that I would like to sort by column. I would like to use the index of that sort to rearrange an array with same dimensions called `unsorted`. I would then like to select the top 2 rows of unsorted.

This is an example of what I have so far that doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np

ranks = np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,5))
unsorted = np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,5))

ind = np.argsort(ranks,axis = 1)
sorted = unsorted[ind]
sorted = sorted[0:2,:]
```

Speed is also an issue as it will be applied to large arrays (50,000 x 5,000).

Comment: Do you only need the top two rows or will you use the rest of the order as well?

Comment: I need the top two and the bottom two, the rest of the sort would be unused.

Comment: Then since you mentioned speed you may want to use `argpartition` instead of `argsort` (linear time vs. log linear).

Comment: What do you mean linear time vs. log linear?

Comment: It basically means the larger your array the faster `argpartition` will be compared to `argsort`.

Comment: Is it possible to sort the bottom two rows and the top two rows but not the middle using ```argpartition```? Or do I have to do two different ```argpartition's```?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. `ranks.argpartition([1,-2],axis=0)` finds the top two and bottom two of each column without sorting the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure we know how to apply `argsort` to `ranks`:

```
In [222]: ranks = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,5)) 
     ...: unsorted = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,5)) 
     ...:  
     ...: ind = np.argsort(ranks,axis = 1)                                                           
In [223]: ranks                                                                                      
Out[223]: 
array([[5, 9, 4, 8, 6],
       [8, 6, 7, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
       [6, 0, 0, 5, 0]])
In [224]: ind                                                                                        
Out[224]: 
array([[2, 0, 4, 3, 1],
       [4, 3, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 4, 3, 0]])
In [225]: np.take_along_axis(ranks, ind, axis=1)                                                     
Out[225]: 
array([[4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
       [1, 3, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 6]])
```

Here each row is ordered.

The pre-take_along method (still works fine) was:

```
In [226]: ranks[np.arange(4)[:,None], ind]                                                           
Out[226]: 
array([[4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
       [1, 3, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 6]])
```

Obviously we could apply this to `unsorted`, though I know what you mean by the top `two rows`.  What's the `two rows` of [226]?

Sorting on 2d arrays is tricky; it's hard to visualize what's happening. I changed your example to use integers and small shape to better visualize the action.

`unsorted[ind]` is not right.  `ind` in this case has values 0...4, the number of columns.  It can't be used to index the first dimension (rows).  In my reduced example the 4 is too large.  Your example runs, but the shape is off `(10,5,5)`.